# Will snowflake stream flush out if we do select count(*) from stream?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Stream has been created on a table and stream is becoming stale after some time. While selecting the stream where condition false most of the time. Also count(*) has been used to check stream count. Will that flush out the stream?

select count(*) from MY_STREAM where false;
With above sql, stream is becoming stale after some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stream advances its offset when it is used in a DML transaction, so SELECT COUNT is not consuming the stream.

It became stale most probably because the MAX_DATA_EXTENSION_TIME_IN_DAYS has been reached (default 14 days).

To view the current staleness status of a stream, execute the DESCRIBE STREAM or SHOW STREAMS command.
The STALE_AFTER column timestamp indicates when the stream is currently predicted to become stale (or when it became stale, if the timestamp is in the past). This is the extended data retention period for the source object.

This timestamp is calculated by adding the larger of the DATA_RETENTION_TIME_IN_DAYS or MAX_DATA_EXTENSION_TIME_IN_DAYS parameter setting for the source object to the current timestamp. Consuming the change data for a stream moves the STALE_AFTER timestamp forward. Note that reading from the stream could succeed for some time after the STALE_AFTER timestamp. However, the stream might become stale at any time during this period. The STALE column indicates whether the stream is currently expected to be stale, though the stream may not actually be stale yet.

For more information, have a look [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams-intro.html#data-retention-period-and-staleness).